# Анализ массива объектов недвижимости в XML

Tags: sql, веб-программирование, xml

Есть массив кадастровых номеров земельных участков и ОКС'ов, в Excel таблице, полученной из файла КПТ в xml. Задача: определить, какой объект имеет статус учтенного/ранее учтенного/без координат границ. Пока единственный костыльный способ это копировать номер и искать информацию на ПКК. Открыл файл xml в редакторе, сравнил между собой несколько объектов, но информацию об учете так и не нашел. Подскажите, есть ли какие либо инструменты для решения проблемы?

Comment: Натуральный "у меня в подполе происходит стук"...

Comment: информативно ....